# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error in emulator, while working in browser

Tags: android, authentication, android-emulator, ionic3

My application was perfectly working in browsers, emulators and android devices before. But recently when I tried, its not working in emulator and android device. I have noted the following points while investigating the issue

- The older version of the same application is running while new one is giving  ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED while login(so it is not related to my network/domain) in emulator/android device
- The same code is working in desktop browser
- Tried with different networks, but failing
- Tried with prod apk and found working(strange)

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Its strange that I have resolved this issue by creating a new Emulator. Phones issue still persists.